# A $1$-completed subgroup is contained in a maximal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Please help me to find a proof for the following fact:

> Suppose $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that there
>   exists $x\in G$ such that $\left<H,x\right>=G$ . Then, $H$ is
>   contained in a maximal subgroup.

Who ensures that a maximal subgroup does exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should assume that $H$ is a *proper* subgroup of $G$, otherwise the case $H = G$ wouldn't work.

It follows $x \notin H$.

Consider the set, ordered by inclusion,
$$
\mathfrak{S} = \{ K : H \le K \le G, x \notin K \}.
$$
(Note that all elements of $\mathfrak{S}$ are *proper* subgroups of $G$, as they do not contain $x$.) This is non-empty, as $H \in \mathfrak{S}$. Consider an ascending chain in $\mathfrak{S}$. Its union is a subgroup, and it does not contain $x$, so it is still in $\mathfrak{S}$.

The hypotheses of [Zorn's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn_lemma) are satisfied, so $\mathfrak{S}$ has a maximal element $M$. To see that $M$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$, just note that if $L$ is a subgroup properly containing $M$, by the very definition of $\mathfrak{S}$ and $M$, the subgroup $L$ must contain $x$. But $L$ contains $M \ge H$, so $L$ contains $H$ and $x$, and thus $L = G$.

This is basically the same argument that shows the existence of maximal ideals in a *ring with identity*.